# jQuery dynamic background position when using .animate method and timer plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Total newbie or noob ;) to jQuery so please be patient with me...

I'm using the standard .animate method along with the timer plugin to loop an animation on two background images, one being the child of it's parent. The effect is a piece of instrument cleaning equipment sliding up and down a guitar string as shown on this link http://sahuspilwal.com/jquery/animate.html

My jQuery code & XHTML is as follows:

```
 $(function(){

     $('#swipe').css({backgroundPosition: '433px 100%'});

     $('#swipe').everyTime(10, function(){
         $('#swipe').animate({backgroundPosition:"(433px 42%)"}, 2000, 'swing');
         $('#swipe').animate({backgroundPosition:"(433px 100%)"}, 2000, 'swing'); 
     });
 });

 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="guitar">
         <div id="swipe"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

However when the content of the containing div exceeds the height of the background image i.e. the guitar it's coordinates of the animation are out of alignment so to speak. See link above for animation with content which has a dynamic height.

Can anyone tell me how I might be able to set the DIV id="swipe" backgroundPosition's values based on the dynamic height of the containing DIV id="guitar" so that the animation is aligned correctly regardless of the height of the parent container??? Hope that makes sense...

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance or feedback.

Kind regards,

Sahus Pilwal

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you can always get the height of any div through jquerys.

```
.height()
.width()
```

you can even get the background images width and height through attr attribute of jquery for image

```
$('#imageid').attr('width');
$('#imageid').attr('height');
```

and then based on the height and width of swipe you can set the height and width of guitar as  follows

```
$('#guitar').css('width',calculated width);
$('guitar').css('height',calculated height)
```

please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Hi Gov, Thanks for the tips. Still not sure how to actually calculate the dynamic height into the #swipe DIV tag

Comment: Hi Gov, Thanks for the tips. Still not sure how to actually calculate the dynamic height into the #swipe DIV tag.  Any ideas how I can get the height of the main guitar container, the height of the background guitar image so I can plot the start and end point of the swipe animation dynamically? Any further feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Sahus